# Check if a particular port is free in Solaris

Tags: java, solaris, serversocket

I had a wierd issue in Solaris 11.3 SPARC machine. I used to check whether the port is free or not using the following method in java(returns true if port is free else returns false).

```
public static boolean isPortFree(int port) {
    try {
        new ServerSocket(port).close();            
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e.getMessage());
        return false;            
    }        
}
```

The above code works fine in all the OS except Solaris. In Solaris machine, when I tested with port 22, it is working as expected, but when I tested with port 12345 which is in use by another process, it is returning true which is the wrong behavior. It should throw an exception saying **Address already in use** and return false.
Please suggest me good idea which works even in Solaris

Comment: Why do you need to check if a port is in use?  Because once you're done checking, the result is invalid as something could start using the port.  If you need to use a port, just use it.  If something else is already using it, you'll get an error.  What you are likely trying to do - check before using - is a [TOCTOU bug - on **every** operating system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Main functionality is written in C and our java code also runs on the same machine. Java code need to get a port from the specified range of ports adn assign it to C process. So, need to check whether the port is already in use by C process or not. If not in use by C process, we will assign it another C process.

Comment: *Java code need to get a port from the specified range of ports adn assign it to C process.* If you assign the port to a process, why do you need to check if it's in use?  That's a serious [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Once a port is assigned to C process, the C process will open the port and use it for it's processing and closes the port once it 's task is done. Java code need to see whether the particular port is in use by any process or not. If it is not in use, it will be allocated to another process

Comment: So you don't know if the child process is still running or not? How do you handle failures if the child process crashed with a `SIGSEGV`? That has an even worse code smell than not keeping track of which ports are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, it is with the IPV4 and IPV6 issue in Solaris machine. C process is opening IPV4 port and the Java's code snippet 
`ServerSocket(port).close();` is checking on the IPV6 port. So that's the reason, it is not throwing any exception in Java even the port(IPV4) is already in use.